# Access date calculations

Tags: ms-access

I have an access Table with a criteria that asks for a value:

```
[LAST CYCLE DATE YYMMDD]
```

I want to replace it with a calculated value for yesterday's date:

```
[LAST-PMT-DATE]=date()-1
```

this returns zero rows

but if I use  [LAST-PMT-DATE]='180611' I get what I expect to see

What is the correct syntax my my calculated date?

Any help would be appreciated!

....further I tried this but get another error:

```
[LAST-PMT-DATE]=FORMAT(DATE()-1,"YYMMDD")
```

Comment: DANG... typo. I changed it to say date()

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
[LAST-PMT-DATE]=FORMAT(DATE()-1,"YYMMDD")
```

The error I was getting, in my example, was the result of an extra ")", that was part of the full piece of code.